# Why is the image going on the next line?

Tags: css, reactjs, image, next.js

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oi7s.png)
The image is moving to the next line for some reason. I have tried several approaches to solve this problem. It seems to be getting better with inbuilt Image component. But there are other issues with that component which is another story. Below is the concerned source code.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSAbb.png)

I want the image and the text on the same line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> the parent div add display: flex, for vertical alignment to the child div use margin: auto

```
function Items({ name, price, category, id, image }) {
  let size = 100;
  return (<div className="py-5 pl-2 m-5 bg-blue-200 d-flex rounded-xl ">
     <div className="my-auto">{name}</div>
     <div className="my-auto">
       <img src={"/api/images/" + image} width={size} height={size} alt={name} />
     </div>
  </div>)
}
```